# Generating unique PDF download link after user input

Tags: forms

I'd like to generate a PDF link after a user inputs his e-mail address. The link needs to be unique (e.g. the real URL to the pdf should not be public). How do I go about this?

Comment: Having some code you can show us, or do you expect we are creating that for you. *(you know how it works on WPSE so please show some own code)*

Comment: Just looking for a general approach. Code is not necessarily what I need.